# To find probabilities in a bivariate normal

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution

I want to find probabilities in R of a Bivariate normal like P(X>3,Y<2), How can I do that?

Thanks for the attention, and excuse my ignorance.

Have a nice day.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=r+bivariate+normal&oq=r+bivari&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1494j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(mvtnorm)
pmvnorm(lower=c(3,-Inf), upper=c(Inf,2), mean=rep(0, 2),
        corr=NULL, sigma=NULL, maxpts = 25000, abseps = 0.001,
        releps = 0)
```

Comment: Hi, I try it but then appear this error Error in rec[, "mean"] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Ok  I try this `sigma1 <-  1.2 
sigma2 <-  1  
rho <- -0.5
Sigma <- matrix(c(sigma1,sigma1*sigma2*rho,sigma1*sigma2*rho,sigma2),ncol=2)
mu <- c(0, 0)
pmvnorm(lower=c(3,-Inf), upper=c(Inf,2), mean=mu,
        corr=NULL, sigma=Sigma, maxpts = 25000, abseps = 0.001,
        releps = 0)`  and it works

Comment: yeah sorry for the typo, I edited my answer!  Glad I could help!

Comment: yes, thanks again :)